# Zabbix trigger expression - number of occurences of current value in the last X minutes

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to write a Zabbix trigger that can detect when my server gets too many requests from the same remote client - like a simple DOS attack.

Specifically, I want to detect that the number of occurrences of the current value for the remote client item is not more than a defined threshold in the last one minute.
I have tried something like this
`{Server:nginx.access.remote.count(1m,{Server:nginx.access.remote.last()},eq)}>10000`

But I get errors saying the expression is incorrect. I guess it is not accepting the expression `{Server:nginx.access.remote.last()}` as an argument for the function `count`.

So ultimately, my logic is this 
`{Server:nginx.access.remote.count(1m,X,eq)}>10000` where X should be the current value, but I don't know how to put the value in the expression.

I would appreciate any help and suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If you check a DOS then {Server:nginx.access.remote.last()} not needed because a DOS will be bigger of any other traffic.

Comment: What type of value is that - is it integer or text?

Comment: @Richlv It's text - the IP address of the remote client

Comment: @AlexeyReytsman What is your suggestion then? For now what I want to do is this: At each time, the trigger checks that the server has not received requests, more than 10,000 times from the current ip - `nginx.access.remote`

Comment: @Ken4scholars I mean you don't need current ip to detect a DOS, and Server:nginx.access.remote.count(1m)}>10000 (or may be more, depending on you usual stats) will be enough. But if you need to detect unusual activity by ip this check don't help you. Unfortunately I don't know how to make it in Zabbix itself, may be you need a something like log analyzer.

Comment: You cannot compare text values in Zabbix, unfortunately. Even if you could, checking 10k or more values would potentially be a performance killer. I'd strongly suggest seeking a more suitable tool for DOS detection and protection.

Comment: @Richlv I totally understand that this is no way near a good check in terms of performance and all that. For now, I just need to be able to check that. If this weren't a text value how could I do that then? From the manuals I can see that text values can be compared but with limited comparison operators like equal and not equal. In a nutshell, I would just like to know how to write an expression to check that the current item value hasn't occured more than X times in the last Y minutes.

Comment: For numeric items you could do something like `last() = last(#2) = last(#3) ...`, but thus would still be limited to a small number of entries, as the trigger expression length is limited. This wouldn't work for text entries, Zabbix cannot compare one non-numeric item value with another.

Comment: @Richlv sorry, but I don't see how the above expression implements my logic of checking that the current item value hasn't occurred more than X times in the last Y minutes. I don't just want to compare a few values. The problem for now is not the text. Let's assume the item is int. I want to know if the last value has occured more than 100 times in the last one minute for example. How can you express that? so far I have not found out how. It looks like something common that should really be easy to express. Not sure why it is not there

Comment: For a larger number of numeric values you could do something like `min(...) = max(...)`. Please note that all values in that timerange or count-range would be kept in the Zabbix value cache.